# Conditional Ext.Template that checks a value from store data

Tags: extjs4

I need to check a value from store data if it exists and only then I want to apply the tpl.

```
'<tpl if="{[values._record.data.TypeofTask]}==1>',
        '<tr>',
        '<th>Constraint Date:</th><td>{[values._record.data.TypeofTask]}</td>',
        '</tr>',
        '</tpl>',
```

However its always is displaying the tpl and not applying the if condition.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'<tpl if="values._record.data.TypeofTask==1">',
```